# Как сделать сложение единых значений?

Tags: c#

Чтобы было понятнее: моя задача - вывести среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел каждого столбца матрицы.

Дело в том, что в коде, изложенном ниже при выводе появляется недочет:
например, при выводе среднего арифметического для 3 столбца данная строчка появляется 2 раза, потому что в этом столбце 2 нечетных значения.

Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы эти значения складывались, но не понимаю как это реализовать.

Заранее спасибо!

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array = new int[3, 6]
        {
            {2,6,1,45,5,22},
            {6,11,34,544,32,11},
            {91,48,75,422,55,88 }
        };
        int[] mas = new int[array.GetLength(1)];
        Console.WriteLine("Вывожу массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j ++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {

                if (array[i, j] % 2 != 0)
                {
                    sum = sum + array[i, j];
                    count = sum;
                        int avg1 = sum / sum;
                    int avg = avg1 * count;
                        int a = j + 1;   
                    Console.WriteLine("Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для " + a + " столбца = " + avg);
                    sum = 0;
                    count = 0;
                    avg1 = 0;
                    avg = 0;
                }
            }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея правильная, но немного перемудрили и запутались.

```cs
int avg1 = sum / sum;
```

Сколько будет, если число разделить само на себя?

```
int avg = avg1 * count;
```

А если то что получилось умножить на другое число?

```cs
avg1 = 0;
avg = 0;
```

Переменные не надо обнулять, если область их объявления в цикле текущая, а не выше, они же переобъявятся заново в следующей итерации цикла.

Вывод в консоль здесь надо для каждого столбца делать, а не для каждой ячейки, поэтому его надо вынести из вложенного цикла.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] array = new int[3, 6]
    {
        { 2,  6, 1, 45, 5,22 },
        { 6, 11,34,544,32,11 },
        { 91,48,75,422,55,88 }
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Вывожу массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i, j] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (array[i, j] % 2 != 0)
            {
                sum += array[i, j];
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для " + (j + 1) + " столбца = " + sum / count);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("В столбце " + (j + 1) + " нет нечетных числел");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Вывожу массив:
2       6       1       45      5       22
6       11      34      544     32      11
91      48      75      422     55      88
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 1 столбца = 91
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 2 столбца = 11
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 3 столбца = 38
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 4 столбца = 45
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 5 столбца = 30
Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для 6 столбца = 11
```