# Создание массива из новых чисел

Tags: c#

Создать массив, состоящий из а чисел ( а = sum / count ).

Т.е. из чисел, которые выводятся на экран с текстом "Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для ... " нужно создать массив.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        int[,] array = new int[3, 6]
        {
            {2,6,1,45,5,22},
            {6,11,34,544,32,11},
            {91,48,75,422,55,88 }
        };
        int[] mas = new int [array.GetLength(1)];
        Console.WriteLine("Вывожу массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {

                if (array[i, j] % 2 != 0)
                {
                    sum = sum + array[i, j];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int a = 0; 
            a = sum / count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Среднее арифметическое для нечетных чисел для " + (j + 1) + " столбца = " + a);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("В столбце " + (j + 1) + " нет нечетных чисел");
            }
            
            int[] mas = { a };
            for ( int z = 0;z<mas.Length;z++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mas[z]);
            }                

        }
    }
```

Comment: В вашем тексте отсутсвует вопрос

Comment: @tym32167 это продолжение истории https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1350157/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже создали массив

```cs
int[] mas = new int[array.GetLength(1)];
```

А вот это уберите

```cs
int[] mas = { a };
```

Кстати

```cs
int a = 0; 
a = sum / count;
```

Можно и нужно записать как

```cs
int a = sum / count;
```

И убрать внутрь условия, потому что если count будет 0, если в колонке не будет нечетных чисел, ваше приложение упадет с исключением "деление на ноль". Проверьте.

Осталось заполнить массив

```cs
if (count > 0)
{
    int a = sum / count;
    mas[j] = a;
}
```

Готово, массив заполнен тем что нужно, теперь после циклов можете организовать вывод значений, например:

```
Console.WriteLine("Массив: " + string.Join(" ", mas));
```